# Why does "t" in "do{j++; t+=j;}while(j<5);" return 15?

Tags: javascript

```
var j=0, t=0;
do{j++; t+=j;}while(j<5);
alert(t);
```

Why does t return 15 in the above code?

Comment: Because 0 + 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 = 15?

Comment: I suggest just writing down what the code does every iteration; it's quite short, and there's nothing tricky about it.

Comment: Because the sum of 1+2+3+4+5 is 15!

Comment: @kevin -- By Grady, I think you have it!!

Comment: Why do you think that it should not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's clean it up:

```
var j = 0;
var t = 0;

do {
  j++;
  t += j;
} while (j < 5);

alert(t);
```

If you manually expand this (and I will), this is the equivalent code without loops:

```
var j = 0;
var t = 0;

j++; // j = 1
t += j;

j++; // j = 2
t += j;

j++; // j = 3
t += j;

j++; // j = 4
t += j;

j++; // j = 5
t += j;

alert(t);
```

Condensing this:

```
var t = 0;

t += 1;
t += 2;
t += 3;
t += 4;
t += 5;

alert(t);
```

Which results in:

```
var t = 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5;

alert(t);
```

And I think you can do simple arithmetic:

```
var t = 15;

alert(t);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because j is incremented before the while test is evaluated, so the loop will be run for the following values of j:

```
j = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
```

Which gives a final value of t of 15 (1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5).

Answer (score 0):

probably 3 pitfalls:

1. do block is always executed once - independent of the condition
2. it uses t+=j so it adds j up to the previous t value
3. when j becomes 5, the do-loop is still executed

here you go:

loop #0:
j=1
t=1

loop #1:
j=2
t=3

loop #2:
j=3
t=6

loop #3:
j=4
t=10

loop #4:
j=5
t=10

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty trivial stuff - you should be able to follow what I have here

```
j = 1; t = 1
j = 2; t = 3
j = 3; t = 6
j = 4; t = 10
j = 5; t = 15
```

Answer (score 0):

Each time that loop runs, j gets incremented. After it gets incremented, t gets j added to it. In the first pass, t is 1. Then j becomes 2, and t is 3, and so on, like this:

```
j=1, t=1
j=2, t=3
j=3, t=6
j=4, t=10
j=5, t=15 (j is not less than 5, loop ends).
```